# How to place Description just after the Legend under a Zend form display group

Tags: zend-form

I am facing a problem in placing description just after the legend and before the elements in a zend form display group.

Here what I have used

```
$form->addDisplayGroup(array($username, $password), 
                        'userLogin', 
                        array(
                        'description' => 'user login description',
                        'legend' => 'user login legend',                                
                        ));

$form->getDisplayGroup('userLogin')
        ->addDecorators(array('Description' , 'FieldSet'));
```

The above code snippet appends the Description after the elements (username and password) but not after the legend.

Any idea how can i place the description just after the legend using Zend_form decorator :-?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar code but mine prints the description before the elements. I'm including a decorator in the middle (*FormElements*), so maybe that's the reason.

```
$form->addDisplayGroup(array($username, $pass), 'userLogin', array(
    'legend' => 'User Login',
    'description' => "Lorem ipsum... "
))->setDisplayGroupDecorators(array('Description', 'FormElements', 'Fieldset'));
```